# Sorting objects in C++

Tags: c++, class, sorting

I have a really strange error when I try and sort objects using a compare method in C++

```
required from 'void std::__final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Album*, std::vector<Album> >; _Compare = bool (*)(const Album*, const Album*)]'
```

It doesn't seem to be a standard error, but I can't see anything wrong with my code. Is it a problem with the compare method, or the sort itself. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have attached the relevant code:

Album.cpp: http://pastebin.com/0tNrbdrT

Album.h: http://pastebin.com/iY2Yy7qM

AlbumCollection.cpp: http://pastebin.com/gWj0nS8S

AlbumCollection.h: http://pastebin.com/bFrxme5n

AlbumCollection Sort:

```
void AlbumCollection::sortAlbums(){
   std::sort(albums.begin(), albums.end(), compareAlbums);
}
```

Album compare method:

```
bool Album::compareAlbums(const Album* a1,const Album* a2)
{
    if (a1->getArtist() == a2->getArtist()){
        return (a1->getTitle() < a2->getTitle());
    }else{
        return a1->getArtist() < a2->getArtist()
    }
}
```

The error is: http://pastebin.com/PeXk0FUT

I'm not sure how much is relevant, I'm quite new to C++

Comment: Please narrow down the code and post it here. [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: That's only a fraction of the error. Please post the lines preceding that one as well.

Comment: Please post the complete error message. I guess you can tell a sentence doesn't start with "required from"

Comment: That's a hell of a lot of code. You should try to shrink it down to a minimal example.

Comment: Just post all the errors. That makes more sense in the context of giving us all the code. But do try to narrow down both.

Comment: why are you using a const Album* instead of const Album&?

Comment: Your comparator should take references to the contained types. Does your container have `Album`s or `Album *`s?

Comment: By the way remove the else and just have `return a1->getArtist() < a2->getArtist();` at the end;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two errors here. First, the compareAlbums function needs to be a free function, not a member function of the Album class. Second, the compareAlbums function must take const-references to Album objects, since that is what you store in your vector. So, this should fix it:

```
bool compareAlbums(const Album& a1,const Album& a2)
{
    if (a1.getArtist() == a2.getArtist()){
        return (a1.getTitle() < a2.getTitle());
    } else {
        return a1.getArtist() < a2.getArtist()
    }
}
```

Comment: The signature in the error message indicates that it's not a nonstatic member function. He might have cut out a `static`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter That's because he has two declarations of compareAlbums in his header file, one as a free function, one as a non-static member function (in both cases, they take in pointers). In the cpp file, however, he only implemented the member function. So, the solution is to drop the member function declaration, update the free function declaration to take const-references instead, and use the definition I provided above in the cpp file.

Comment: ah, he was cruising for a link error. Note that you can't obtain a PTMF without using using the special syntax `&Album::compareAlbums` which is an unlikely newbie error.

Answer (score 1):

You've tried to sort a `std::vector` using a function that takes pointers as arguments. The comparison function is given references to its arguments, not pointers.

The immediate problem should be fixed simply by taking the comparison function and adjusting it from

```
bool compare(const Album*, const Album*)
```

to

```
bool compare(Album const &, Album const &)
```